# Expires instead of Max-Age

Tags: http, caching, cache-control, mod-expires, expires-header

We are using the Google Page Speed Tool.

It says we should use "Leverage Browser Caching" for images.

In the httpd.conf we use "ExpiresByType" with 1 month.

The "max-age" in the response of the image is set to 1 month but the "Expires" is set to 1 day.

Google Page speed is ignoring the "Max-age" and interpreting the "Expires" and thus giving the warning.

How can we set the "Expires" instead of "Max-age" though Mod_expires?

Answer (score 0):

> Google Page speed is ignoring the "Max-age" and interpreting the "Expires" and thus giving the warning.

That would be a bug. [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) states:

> If a response includes a Cache-Control field with the max-age
> directive (Section 5.2.2.8), a recipient MUST ignore the Expires
> field.

By default, [`mod_expires` controls](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html)

> the setting of the Expires HTTP header and the max-age directive of the Cache-Control HTTP header in server responses.

So both headers should contain the same effective expiry time.

You may have another setting (`mod_headers`?), you may be misinterpreting the headers, an extra proxy may be involved or you could have found a bug.